# Starting SQL Dev on Mac?

Tags: sql, macos

As I've never created an SQL database outside of University, I'd really like to get a bit of experience. At this moment in time I use a Mac and I've googled round but can't find any decent links.

At the moment I have the mySQL Query Browser / Administrator, which I use for work when I bring my laptop in.

However what additional software do I need in order to *create* a database on my Mac? Can anyone provide any links for software they recommend?

I have mySQL installed at the command line at the moment, however I haven't a clue as to what I'm supposed to do and I'd like some help getting my feet on the ground. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#macosx-dmg

Comment: For a list of SQL server products that run on Mac OS X, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19809782/642706) on the question *Create sql database on mac*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check MAMP, Mac, Apache, MySQL and PHP.
It comes loaded with a database and a ready to go application server.

After setting up MySQL, you will need an editor to make a database and tables. I know Navicat for Windows/Mac is one of the best for MySQL but its commercial. You will need to look for other GUI.

I also tried PostgreSQL database, it does have a GUI and its free.

Answer (score 2):

A really nice MySQL management application is [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/). Works way better than the official MySQL software and phpMyAdmin in my opinion. You should take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to install anything else if you're happy to use Python. Python 2.5 and later include SQLite, so as long as you have Leopard or Snow Leopard you can use that.

You could try [this link](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) to start off. It includes a listing to create a minimal SQLite shell.

Alternativel, why not try http://www.sqlcourse.com/ ? That includes a web-based interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way to learn is with the CLI client.

But that sqlcourse website looks like it has a decent didactive concept, so why not stick with that for a start?